# If statement in terraform, using 2 different code blocks

Tags: if-statement, terraform

I have this codeblock

```
  launchpad_tmpl = {
    apiVersion = "<Link for the API>"
    kind       = "mke"
    spec = {
      mke = {
        adminUsername = "admin"
        adminPassword = var.admin_password
        installFlags : [
          "--default-node-orchestrator=kubernetes",
          "--san=${module.masters.lb_dns_name}",
        ]
      }
      hosts = concat(local.managers, local.msrs, local.workers, local.windows_workers)
    }
  }
}
```

And I have another codeblock

```
  launchpad_tmpl = {
    apiVersion = "<Some link for the API>"
    kind       = "mke"
    spec = {
      mke = {
        adminUsername = "admin"
        adminPassword = var.admin_password
        installFlags : [
          "--default-node-orchestrator=kubernetes",
          "--san=${module.masters.lb_dns_name}",
        ]
      }

      msr = {
      ...some_code
      }
      hosts = concat(local.managers, local.msrs, local.workers, local.windows_workers)
    }
  }
}
```

I want to tell terraform something like

IF msr_count >= 1 - Use second codeblock to run
ELSE use the first one...

Is it possible in Terraform Or I will need to make a wrapper somewhere?
Thanks in Advance.

UPDATE:::

```
 Error: Inconsistent conditional result types

  on main.tf line 162, in output "mke_cluster":
 162:   value = yamlencode(var.msr_count > 0 ? local.msr_launchpad_tmpl : local.mke_launchpad_tmpl)
    |----------------
    | local.mke_launchpad_tmpl is object with 3 attributes
    | local.msr_launchpad_tmpl is object with 3 attributes
    | var.msr_count is 1

The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The given
expressions are object and object, respectively.
```

This is the output when it placed like this:

```
 mke_launchpad_tmpl = {
    apiVersion = "API"
    kind       = "mke"
    spec = {
      mke = {
        adminUsername = "admin"
        adminPassword = var.admin_password
        installFlags : [
          "--default-node-orchestrator=kubernetes",
          "--san=${module.masters.lb_dns_name}",
        ]
      }
      hosts = concat(local.managers, local.msrs, local.workers, local.windows_workers)
    }
  }


  msr_launchpad_tmpl = {
    apiVersion = "API"
    kind       = "mke+msr"
    spec = {
      mke = {
        adminUsername = "admin"
        adminPassword = var.admin_password
        installFlags : [
          "--default-node-orchestrator=kubernetes",
          "--san=${module.masters.lb_dns_name}",
        ]
      }
      msr = {
        installFlags : [
          "--ucp-insecure-tls",
          "--dtr-external-url ${module.msrs.lb_dns_name}",
        ]
        }
    hosts = concat(local.managers, local.msrs, local.workers, local.windows_workers)
    }
  }
  launchpad_tmpl = var.msr_count > 0 ? local.msr_launchpad_tmpl : local.mke_launchpad_tmpl
}

output "mke_cluster" {
  value = yamlencode(local.launchpad_tmpl)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [conditional expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/conditionals.html). Also for simplicity, you can create the two alternatives as locals, which will simplify the expression.

For example:

```
locals {

 mke_launchpad_tmpl = {
    apiVersion = "API"
    kind       = "mke"
    spec = {
      mke = {
        adminUsername = "admin"
        adminPassword = var.admin_password
        installFlags : [
          "--default-node-orchestrator=kubernetes",
          "--san=${module.masters.lb_dns_name}",
        ]
      }
      msr = {}
      hosts = concat(local.managers, local.msrs, local.workers, local.windows_workers)
    }
  }


  msr_launchpad_tmpl = {
    apiVersion = "API"
    kind       = "mke+msr"
    spec = {
      mke = {
        adminUsername = "admin"
        adminPassword = var.admin_password
        installFlags : [
          "--default-node-orchestrator=kubernetes",
          "--san=${module.masters.lb_dns_name}",
        ]
      }
      msr = {
        installFlags : [
          "--ucp-insecure-tls",
          "--dtr-external-url ${module.msrs.lb_dns_name}",
        ]
        }
    hosts = concat(local.managers, local.msrs, local.workers, local.windows_workers)
    }
  }

}
```

Then, in your resource:

```
launchpad_tmpl = var.msr_count > -1 ? local.second_launchpad_tmpl : local.first_launchpad_tmpl
```

Comment: Hey, I followed your answer seems something not good. Edited my questions

Comment: @SemyonKolesnikov I don't see any new error message?

Comment: see UPDATE::: please it's error message right after this.

Comment: @SemyonKolesnikov Your `mke_launchpad_tmpl` and `mke_launchpad_tmpl` have different form. I updated the answer to make them have some form.

Comment: Thank you very much @Marcin It's working now. Why do we need to put an empty section of the MSR in mke template?

Comment: @SemyonKolesnikov This will make these two variables exhibiting same form, but different values. Conditions require this, which can be confusing.